# XLSX library for Kotlin Native

Tags: xlsx, kotlin-native

I am working on a Kotlin Native project, which main purpose is to generate reports in `.xlsx` format. Which library should I use for working with `.xlsx` files? I only need to create new files, so the ability to read existing Excel files is not necessary.

For background information: I am using Kotlin Native in order to bypass JVM startup time, because my each time a report is needed a separated process is started.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to choose any C library you find yourself comfortable with. Thanks to `cinterop` tool, Kotlin/Native can use already known and polished instruments from the C world. There are several samples in the repository.

As an example, I just found [this one](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io).